# Select html. Что нужно отправлять на сервер при выборе элемента?

Tags: веб-программирование

Меня интересует если мне надо было добавить в таблицу по связи один ко многим id элемента например "понедельник" то мне отравлять value с его id в таблице или текст "Понедельник"?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос ясный, но не совсем корректный.

1. Что если у вас в id хранится "Понедельник"?
2. Нужен ли id вам на сервере или это каскадный select параметер или текстовый фильтр?
3. ...

это полная вкусовщина так как всё зависит от задачи. Отправляйте то что нужно если нужно id то передавайте его.

Comment: Id нужно на сервере для объединения с таблицей